# Showing that the set of all cofinite sets is a filter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

1. Let $F = \{B \subseteq\mathbb N : \mathbb N\setminus B\text{ is finite}\}$. Show that $F$ is a filter on $\mathbb N$.
2. Let $A$ be a non-empty set. Let $a\in A$. Let $F = \{B \subseteq A : a \in B\}$.
   Show that $F$ is a filter on $A$.

How to show this? please help

Comment: You undoubtedly have a definition of filter in your book/notes. For 1) and 2) checking that $F$ satisifies the definition should be fairly mechanical. Please indicate what property you had difficulty in verifying.

Comment: the intersection and subset part. the last two parts

Comment: @AndréNicolas its the intersection and subset part

Comment: For 1), (a) suppose that the complement of $X$ is finite, and $X\subseteq Y$. Then the complement of $Y$ is finite, so $Y\in F$. (b) Suppose the complement of $X$ and of $Y$ is finite. We have $(X\cap Y)'=X'\cup Y'$, so the complement of $X\cap Y$ is finite, and therefore $X\cap Y\in F$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you very much. I am assuming X=B and Y=Natural numbers

Comment: No, André meant $Y \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, just like $X$. You can rename his $X, Y$ to $A, B$ if you like.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: The first one is called cofinite filter or [Frechet filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_filter). Is there something unclear in the proof given in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you very much

Comment: @MartinSleziak The proof is not clear

Answer (score 3):

The filter $F = \{B \subseteq\mathbb N : \mathbb N\setminus B\text{ is finite}\}$ is called [Fréchet filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_filter) or cofinite filter. Since you wrote [in your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470681/showing-that-a-variable-is-a-filter#comment2997635_1470681) that the proof given on Wikipedia seems unclear to you, I will try to add a bit more details.

To show that $F$ is a [filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29#Filter_on_a_set) on $\mathbb N$, we need to show three things:

- $\emptyset\notin F$, $\mathbb N\in F$
- If $A,B\in F$, then $A\cap B\in F$.
- If $A\subseteq B\subseteq\mathbb N$, then $B\in F$.

The first part is clear: We have $\mathbb N\setminus\mathbb N=\emptyset$, so $\mathbb N$ is cofinite and it belongs to $F$. Similarly, we have $\mathbb N\setminus\emptyset=\mathbb N$, which is not finite, hence $\emptyset\notin F$.

Now if $A$ and $B$ are cofinite, this means that both $\mathbb N\setminus A$ and $\mathbb N\setminus B$ are finite. Using [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) we get
$$\mathbb N\setminus (A\cap B)=(\mathbb N\setminus A)\cup(\mathbb N\setminus B).$$
So this is union of two finite sets, which is again a finite set. Thus $A\cap B\in F$.

Now let $A\in F$ and let $B$ be a subset of $\mathbb N$ such that $B\supseteq A$. Then we have
$$\mathbb N\setminus B \subseteq \mathbb N\setminus A.$$
Since the set $\mathbb N\setminus A$ is finite and $\mathbb N\setminus B$ is a subset of this set, the set $\mathbb N\setminus B$ is finite, too. This means that $B\in F$.

---

The filter of the form $F=\{B\subseteq A; a\in B\}$ is called principal ultrafilter on $A$. Again you should ask:

- Does $\emptyset$ belong to $F$? I.e., does $a\in\emptyset$ hold?
- Does $A\in F$? I.e., does $a\in A$ hold?
- If you know that $a\in B_1,B_2$ what can you say about $B_1\cap B_2$.
- If you know that $a\in B_1$ and $B_1\subseteq B_2$, does this mean that $a\in B_2$?