# On the filters on $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of natural numbers. Then I claim that the set
$\mathscr{F}$ which contains cofinite subsets on $\mathbb{N}$
Is a filter on $\mathbb{N}$.

I actually want to prove the claim and here's my attempt.

**My attempt:-**

So we need to prove that $\mathscr{F}$ satisfies two axioms of filters.

Let, $A,B\in\mathscr{F}$. Then $X/A,X/B$ are finite sets by definition so their union is also finite.

$$(X/A)\cup(X/B)=X/(A \cap B)$$
So $A\cap B\in\mathscr{F}$ as required.
Now I am unable to prove the second axiom which states that,

$$A\in\mathscr{F},A\subseteq B\subseteq X \implies B\in\mathscr{F}$$
I tried it in some ways but found nothing. Any proof of this will really be helpful.

Comment: If $A\subseteq B,$ then $X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A.$

Comment: You want `\setminus` for $\setminus$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the notation, the first condition is ok. (I will use $X\setminus A$ to denote a difference of two sets. Other common notation is $X-A$.)

If you have that $A$ is cofinite and $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$ then you also have
$$X\setminus B\subseteq X\setminus A.$$
Since $X\setminus A$ is finite, the subset $X\setminus B$ is also finite. This shows that $B$ is cofinite.

I will add that this filter is also called [Fréchet filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_filter). (And the linked Wikipedia article contains a proof that it is actually a filter.)

See also: [Showing that the set of all cofinite sets is a filter](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470681).